# List Style Type None not working

Tags: css

When I was building my site, I typed the following codes. However, the List Style Type None None code didn't remove the dot/bullet before every item. I've tried !important and failed. Could anyone tell me why?

```css
.naviMenu 
{
  list-style-type: none !important;
}`
```

```html
<div class="naviMenu">
    <ul>
  <div id="homePage"><li>Home</li></div>
  <li>About</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Photo</li>
  <li>Special Project</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You're targeting the wrong element

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason your **CSS** is not working is because the `list-style-type` property must be attached to a display: list-item element such as `li` or `ul`. (As **@andrewli** stated you're targeting the wrong element).

You can do this like so

```
.naviMenu > ul li { // notice how I have targeted the li element(s) rather than the whole parent container
    list-style-type: none; // also, there is no need for !important 
}
```

**Just as a little side note**

This line of markup:

```
<ul>
    <div id="homePage"><li>Home</li></div>
    <!-- e.t.c. !-->
</ul>
```

Contains incorrect syntax. It **should** be done like so:

```
<ul>
    <li><div id="homePage">Home</div></li>
    <!-- e.t.c. !-->
</ul>
```

Hope this helps! :-)

Comment: @torazaburo sure, you can also do it on the `ul` tag :) I just prefer to do it on the `li` haha

Comment: Sure, but the fact remains that saying *the `list-style-type` property **must** be attached to a `li` element* is incorrect. It would be correct to say that "the `list-style-type` property takes effect on elements with `display: list-item` (such as an `li` element), and may be inherited from any ancestor element (but note that the user agent style sheet for `ul` will usually set a value such as `disc`)."

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
.naviMenu ul li{
    list-style-type:none;
}
```

Comment: please go throught this link - http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_list.asp. and please mark it as answer

Comment: because "naviMenu" is just a div and in order for the bullets to be hidden you need to put it in the `li` itself because that's where the bullets are.

Comment: `.naviMenu ul { list-style: none; }` would suffice too and targets just the list instead of each bullet.